# CiviVolunteer - Where to put translations file on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, installation, civivolunteer, localisation, i18n

after some work on Transifex, we need to install civiVolunteer italian translation on WordPress. Where is the right place to put the .mo file?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update/blob/master/l10nupdate.php#L131 it looks like it needs to be within the extension folder in folders 10n//LC_Messages/volunteer.mo This line details the download path for the mo https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update/blob/master/l10nupdate.php#L130 the mo is the binary version of the .po files i believe

Comment: Trying to generate .mo file and move it in the same civicrm.mo folder, which is:
`/site-folder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/l10n/it_IT/LC_MESSAGES`

having this situation 
`-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1690874 Jan  6 19:40 civicrm.mo
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    9017 Jan  7 19:09 volunteer.mo`
there is no translation visible.

Comment: @FrancescoGarganese you should be able to download the .mo file from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-l10n-extensions/mo/volunteer/it_IT/volunteer.mo There is a job that automatically generates the .mo and stores it in a google storage bucket for people to download

Comment: thank you for the very useful link. The only issue now remains: where to put the .mo file to be considered by CiviVolunteer?

Comment: As per my original comment you put it within the Extension's directory in sub folder l10n/<language>/LC_Messages/<mo file>

I would also recommend you look at using that 10n update extension. It would likely just handle everything for you.